# Database recommendation for distributed email archive with attachments

Tags: database, email, clustering, email-attachments

I'm looking for a database engine that will be used as e-mail storage solution

Each record will represent email with all typical fields:

- sender
- recipient
- cc/bcc
- subject
- body
- text only version of body
- attachments with original filenames + contents of attachments as binary data

My project is a proof-of-concept. I'd like to start with single database server, but if it will succeed need to easily add next servers

Key features I'm looking for:

- Should work well on low-memory commodity hardware. Servers with huge HDD but small CPU/RAM
- Clustering/Replication
- Ease of scaling up. Need more capacity? Add more servers
- Cluster should allow live node addition and automatically re-balancing and re-sharding
- Adding new servers should not need a DBA with 10 years of experience or reading through 1000 pages of manuals

Any recommendations?